# Excel Custom Format meaning

Tags: excel

What is this custom formatting actually doing if anything? 
Why is [$-11809] there?

**[$-11809]dd/mm/yyyy**

```
Raw Value           42521.5565907755 
In Formula Bar      31/05/2016  13:21:29 
Custom Format       [$-11809]dd/mm/yyyy
Display in Cell     31/05/2016
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It represents a locale ID - [here's a list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/goglobal/bb964664.aspx)  from MSDN. But it seems like there is is maybe a typo. The decimal format for Lao is 1108 and the hexdecimal format for Ireland is 1809 - but nothing for 11809.

See [this post](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/03/11/change-date-format-excel/) as well.

Comment: Thanks,   yes seems like a Typo , should be 1809 - no  wonder my google searches yielded nothing!